# exec: "firefox": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: go, path, zsh

I am reading a go book to learn go writing command line tools. In one of the examples I need to open firefox browser with an html file. The command run is:

```
browserPath,_ := exec.LookPath("firefox")

// Open the file on the browser
if err := exec.Command(browserPath, "index.html").Start(); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

But get the error:

```
exec: "firefox": executable file not found in $PATH
```

My $PATH is:

```
$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

I am running on mac with zsh. I looked at similar problems but can't solve it yet, anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: Does you running `firefox` from a terminal window work? You can try adding the directory with the firefox executable to your path

Comment: I want to reopen this question, I fixed the issue (after many hours working it alone since it was closed) and want to post my answer since I think it can help others. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all thank you for reopening the question, I understand it might be trivial to many, but it can help someone else to see this answer.

The issue was (as @xarantolus commented) that my PATH did not contain the route to my `/Applications` folder. Since I use `zsh` and mac, I did the following steps to fix it:

**First find where firefox executable was:**

```
$ type -a firefox
```

Printed route:

```
firefox is /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
```

**Now open zshrc file:**

```
$ vim ~/.zshrc
```

**Inside the file, my `$PATH` was `$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`, and I added `/Applications` so the line ended up like this:**

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/:$PATH
```

Notice that `:$PATH` will be at end also after adding the new path

**Then run command to reload .zshrc**

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

If you dont use zsh, use the file .bashrc instead of .zshrc

Go could now see the firefox executable and it opened it as expected.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac you have a command available called open which opens the default browser.

I have the same book as you. I hope the author fixes this. Would be nice to open the default browser regardless of the host operating system. There might be a way. I didn't look for a command similar to open on linux or windows.

https://gist.github.com/ivorscott/3ddba5527e5a96136bf870a57a37e721